# How to begin with i18n-ally

Tags: internationalization, vscode-extensions

Just try to translate my own vscode extension. Nothing is working and i don't find a "get started" for i18n-ally.
file to translate are json, typescript and python.

Is anyone can help me ?

Comment: If you check any Microsoft extension (like the Python one https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python) you can learn how they use package.nls.xx.json to achieve Internationalization.